# Sending information using paypal API without creating a complete payment

Tags: paypal

Is there a way to use the paypal API to send basic details of a payment without actually creating the payment itself?  What I mean is, I'm working with a non profit organization that does not currently employ SSL.  They want to use paypal to accept donations, but they want their own branded form on their page, they don't want to use the simple donate button.  I had thought I might be able to send basic details, such as name and address along with the amount they wish to donate and a few other details using the paypal API, and then have the actual payment information processed on paypal's secure servers.  All the examples I can find on how to use their API however are creating complete payments and sending them to Paypal, something I'm not able to do for obvious reasons.  Short of employing SSL, something that we should probably do anyways, and capturing a complete payment, is there a way of sending just select information over the API and handling the rest on paypal's end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to control the form itself you don't have any choice but to go SSL. Any other route would require sending the user to PayPal, where you would no longer have that control.